# Display none in table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I do a display none in div with id="NoveMeses" if all elements from h3 show "N.A"?

If h3 from div row1 and row2 show me the span="N.A", I want to display none the div NoveMeses.

There is my code using AngularJs

```
<div id="NoveMeses" data-ng-if=$odd class="tableRowOdd" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '9M'">
          <div class="tableCellContent20">
                   <h3 class="cellTextType" ><span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
          </div>

          <div id="row1" class="tableCellContent20">
                   <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                   <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="!item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
          </div>

          <div id="row2" class="tableCellContent20">
                   <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
                   <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="!item.TipoOWS !== 'Datas'"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
          </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you could do something similar to below. It gets all `<h3>` elements from your `<div id="NoveMess">`, counts them, then checks if each is equal to "N.A".

jQuery:

```
var trueList = [];
$(".NoveMess h3").each(function(){
    trueList.push( (this.textContent.trim() === "N.A") );
});
if( trueList.includes(false) )
    $(".NoveMess").hide();
```

Vanilla Javascript:

```
var trueList = [];
var parentContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("NoveMess")[0];
var childH3Containers = parentContainer.getElementsByTagName("H3");

for(var text in childH3Containers){
    trueList.push( (text.textContent.trim() === "N.A") )
}

if( trueList.includes(false) )
    parentContainer.style.display = "none";
```

Again, these are untested, but I believe the concept is sound.